# Dynamically generate WPF TreeView issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, treeview

I want to build a FileExplorer by WPF.

1. I download the code from here and it works in my Visual Studio 2022 with .net 6.0. (I use Upgrade Assistant to upgrade)
   https://github.com/mikependon/RepoDB.Tutorials/tree/master/WPF/TreeViewFileExplorer/TreeViewFileExplorer
2. I import this project into my solution and copy the code of MainWindow.xaml/cs and to mine and it still works, I can show it in my ap.
3. Because it's XAML based and I want to use C# to generate the TreeView.

**Original XAML code:**

```
<TreeView Name="treeViewX" Margin="5">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.AcceptsReturn" Value="True" />
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type fileexplorer:FileSystemObjectInfo}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="0,1,8,1"></Image>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FileSystemInfo.Name}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

**New C# code:**

```
treeViewX = new();
treeViewX.Margin = new Thickness(5);
treeViewX.Name = "treeViewX";

Style treeViewItemStyle = new Style(typeof(TreeViewItem));
treeViewItemStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(TreeViewItem.IsExpandedProperty, new Binding("IsExpanded") { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay }));
treeViewItemStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(KeyboardNavigation.AcceptsReturnProperty, true));
treeViewX.ItemContainerStyle = treeViewItemStyle;

HierarchicalDataTemplate dataTemplate = new(typeof(FileSystemObjectInfo));
dataTemplate.ItemsSource = new Binding("Children");

dataTemplate.VisualTree = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
dataTemplate.VisualTree.SetValue(StackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Horizontal);

FrameworkElementFactory imageFactory = new(typeof(Image));
Binding imageBinding = new("ImageSource");
imageBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
imageFactory.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, imageBinding);
imageFactory.SetValue(Image.MarginProperty, new Thickness(0, 1, 8, 1));
dataTemplate.VisualTree.AppendChild(imageFactory);

FrameworkElementFactory textBlockFactory = new(typeof(TextBlock));
Binding textBinding = new("FileSystemInfo.Name");
textBlockFactory.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, textBinding);
dataTemplate.VisualTree.AppendChild(textBlockFactory);

dockPanelLeft1.Children.Add(treeViewX);
InitializeFileSystemObjects();
```

**Test Result:**
The following is the result. My computer has 3 disks and it shows 3 lines on the screen only.

[image]

I think it means the code can get 3 disks successfully, but it cannot show the detail. It seems something wrong in the data binding, is there any suggestion?

The code of `InitializeFileSystemObjects();` is [here](https://github.com/mikependon/RepoDB.Tutorials/blob/9cca15b7db17c44095d022bc1dba9f57b8b98b00/WPF/TreeViewFileExplorer/TreeViewFileExplorer/MainWindow.xaml.cs#L37): I don't paste it because I don't change it. And it works for my XAML code, I guess it should be correct.

Comment: Looks like you've not got a datatemplate for that type. You get the name of the type if there's no datatemplate. The namespace is different?

Comment: Why do you want to use c# to generate your treeview? It'll be far harder to do than if you use xaml.

Comment: @Andy, HierarchicalDataTemplate is c#'s built-in class, should I add it in the namespace? And because I want to generate several tree view dynamically, therefore, I need to use C# to generate the tree view.

Comment: @Dennys All you need to generate the TreeView dynamically is a set of DataTemplates and a data source/data structure. If your requirements are more complex you can even consider to implement a DataTemplateSelector. You never need to create templates in C# (except if you need to deserialize a template). The API that is necessary (FrameworkElementFactory ) is even deprecated. Don't tell me that your code is readable and not overly complex and complicated when compared to its equivalent XAML markup.

Comment: @BionicCode, I agree it's not a good idea to use C# to generate XAML. I don't need to deserialize it, but I need to create several TreeView dynamically. As I know, if I use XAML, I need to decide the number of TreeView at design time. I'm not an expert, is it possible to use XAML only and I can have several TreeViews?

Comment: You should define the TreeView as part of a DataTemplate. What exactly are you trying to achieve?